# PHP Session Destroy

Tags: php, mysql, database, session, destroy

How do I destroy a session in php?

the thing is when the user clicks the logout button the session will end and he will be redirected to the index.php here's my code

Customer.php

```
<?php 

session_start(); 
#include("Connection.php");
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
$name = $_POST['customerName']; 
$_SESSION['user'] = $name; 
} 
if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) { echo "Hello {$_SESSION['user']}, welcome back"; }
else{echo "walang tao";}

$sql="INSERT INTO ORDERS(Name) VALUES('$name')";
mysql_query($sql);

session_destroy();
?>
<button><a href="Customer.php"></a></button>
```

and this is from the index.php where the user wants to log in again

```
<?PHP 
/* this must go before any html */ 
session_start(); 

if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) { 
header("location: Customer.php"); 
} 
?> 
     <div class="sign">
                    <h2>Welcome</h2>
                    <form action = "Customer.php" method = "POST">
                    Customer Name:<input type = "text" name="customerName">
                    <input type = "submit" name = "submit">
                    </form>
```

Comment: replace the index.php with Customer.php

Comment: http://php.net/session_destroy

Comment: Say hello to `Bobby Tables` for me when you see him.

Comment: There already is a `session_destroy` call in your Customer.php file? Where does the 'logout button' link to?

Comment: because I want the user to redirected to the index.php page

Comment: Used prepared statements, you can use my [1kB PDO library](https://github.com/Xeoncross/DByte) if you need something simple.

Answer (score 4):

```
session_start();
session_destroy();
```

Answer (score 1):

You may also used `unset()` function for free up session Environment.

```
if (isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
  unset($_SESSION['user']);
  header('location:index.php');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Include this file in your header and set the required settings in file.
It should work well.

```
<?php
    session_cache_expire(20);
    if (!isset($_SESSION)) {    
        session_start();
    }
    // set timeout period in seconds
    $inactive = 1200; // timeout for the session
    // check to see if $_SESSION['timeout'] is set
    if(isset($_SESSION['timeout']) ) {
        $session_life = time() - $_SESSION['timeout'];
        if($session_life > $inactive) {
            $_SESSION = array();
            if(isset($_COOKIE[session_name()])) {
                setcookie(session_name(), '', time()-42000, '/');
            } 
            session_destroy(); 
            header("Location: index.php"); // or whatever you prefer to do. 
        }
    }
    $_SESSION['timeout'] = time();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't using the auth component then its really easy

```
public function logout(){
    $this->Session->destroy();
    // no cake we really want you to delete it because you suck
    $this->Session->destroy();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//If you want complete destroy session then you can write.
```

session_destroy();

The session_unset() //function frees all session variables currently registered.