# Change profile picture while log out PHP

Tags: php, html

on my app when user log out, there is a redirection to login page and email is unset but I also want to unset the profile picture because right now when user is redirect to login page it display his profile picture even though he's log out.  I want to display default picture which is './assets/profile-picture/avatar.jpg'

The code looks like that:

```
<?php
session_start();
unset($_SESSION['email']);
$_SESSION['profileImage'] = './assets/profile-picture/avatar.jpg';
// unset ($_SESSION['profileImage']);

header("Location: login.php");

exit;
?>


             



<img src=<?php echo isset($user['profileImage']) ? $user['profileImage']: "./assets/profile-picture/avatar.jpg" ; ?> style="width: 200px; height: 200px" class="img rounded-circle" alt="profile">
```

I also try unset which is comment but none of that worked. Thanks for any clue.

Comment: you can use php session_destroy() funciton which unsets all sessions and destroy them

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP Session Destroy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244581/php-session-destroy)